# Want to know how I can change the header through the tabview style property?

Tags: css, primefaces, tabview

I'm doing a project using: jsf, primefaces, css layout editing ...
I need to change the background of just one tabview without affecting all other tabviews in the project.
I know there is a property: .ui-widget-header.
If I change this property in the css file, all headers are changed.
Want to know how I can change the heater through the tabview style property?

I tried this in css, but it changes all headers:

```
 .ui-widget-header {
      border: 1px solid #56585C;
      background: #424548;
      color: #F9F7F7;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

My goal is to take a background from a tabView contained in another tabView without affecting the main tabView

Comment: There is no plain java in your question, please remove ot from the tags

Comment: Thanks! @Kukeltje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your tabView a class:

```
<p:tabView styleClass="certain-tabview-class"
```

Use CSS descendant selector to style only tabViews with this class:

```
.certain-tabview-class .ui-widget-header {
```

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles

Comment: This pretty much solved my problem. Thanks!  @Kukeltje